# How do I assign an std::function to an operator in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operators, function-object

```
template<class Key, class Value>
AVLTree<Key,Value>::AVLTree(){
    this->lessThan = Key::operator<;
}
```

This code is supposed to make the `std::function<bool(Key, Key)> lessThan` field equal to the key's < operator by default. However, when I try this with `AVLTree<int,int>`, I get:

```
error: ‘operator<’ is not a member of ‘int’
```

Am I formatting this wrong, or is this just impossible in C++?

Comment: your assumption is that `operator<` is a member function but it isn't in the general case and definitely not for `int`, use `std::less`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no pre-existing function in C++ that performs comparison on `int`s. Furthermore, even if `Key` is a class type, you can't know whether it has a member or non-member `operator<`.

Here are some alternatives:

1. Use `std::less`,

   ```
   this->lessThan = std::less<Key>();
   ```
2. Use a lambda:

   ```
   this->lessThan = [](const Key& k1, const Key& k2){ return k1 < k2; };
   ```
3. If you design `AVLTree` like the standard library containers, the type of the comparison object should be a type template parameter `Comp` defaulting to `std::less<Key>`, with an instance passed in the constructor, defaulting to `Comp()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class Key, class Value>
AVLTree<Key,Value>::AVLTree()
{
    this->lessThan = std::less<Key>();
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Template Specialization for built-in types like `int`, `double`, `char`, etc. It's impossible to query for the relational operators on built-in types, which causes your code to fail.